# Shooting Solar Eclipse with an ND 100000 Marumi - Mirrorless Camera

Tags: mirrorless, sun, eclipse, nd-filter

My gear:
Sony Alpha A6400 (1.5x crop) **Mirrorless Camera**,
Sony 70-200mm f2.8 G lens @ 200mm (300mm after crop),
Marumi ND 100,000 Filter.

The mirrorless camera does not have a mirror in front of its sensor, exposing the sensor to the SUN 100% of the time through the ND filter while shooting the entire eclipse, which is roughly 3 hours.

**Annular Eclipse** starts at 8AM and goes on till 11AM

I could not find a Solar filter, so I got myself an **ND100000. This filter is specialized for solar shooting according to the provider [here](https://www.marumi-filter.co.jp/en/product/03/#nd100000)**

I'm going to practice taking some shots, and build a timeline on how to take the shots, at what intervals etc,. I will be wearing a solar eclipse glass the entire time, unless I want to see the Live view on the camera.

Question 1: 
Will I damage my sensor or lens(rented lens) even after using a ND100000 filter? I'm thinking of closing or covering the front element of the lens of the camera after ever shot, so the sensor is not exposed the entire time, as it is a mirrorless camera.

Question 2: **removed**

Question 3:
I will have to open the shutter up for like a few minutes to get the focus on point initially, will this damage the sensor or lens? Can I focus on the SUN while the ND filter is **on** the lens? (I mean is there any other way?)

Positive reviews by the people who had actually shot [using the ND100000 and DSLR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0068V25JE), not a mirrorless camera.

Thanks...

Comment: Looking at [this](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2017/09/rental-camera-gear-destroyed-by-the-solar-eclipse-of-2017/), the damage may not be on your sensor...

Comment: @xenoid I will try to set the aperture fully open at f2.8 and see the amount of light coming out of the lens on the other side, by keeping a thin cotton piece. If it is not hot, which means I'm safe right?

Comment: @xenoid The damage to that aperture diaphragm was because the filter was placed in a "drop-in" slot *behind* most of the lens, rather than on the front of the lens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of filter do I need for safe sun photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101159/what-kind-of-filter-do-i-need-for-safe-sun-photography)

Comment: @MichaelC Partly but not really. I'm using a mirrorless, and I'm using a 16stop ND. But your answer gives me more knowledge thanks.

Comment: I strongly reccomend that you use this instead: http://thousandoaksoptical.com/ "Used by NASA aboard the Space Shuttle. Other professional users include: ABC, BBC, CBS, NBC, CNN, NOVA, The Discovery Channel, National Geographic, and most major universities and observatories throughout the world." I use and endorse thier product. I had no damage to my Nikon D800 sensor or otherwise in the August 21, 2017 eclipse here in the USA.

Comment: Thousand Oaks film is also what I made my solar filters with to capture the August 21, 2017 total solar eclipse.

Comment: Third user of Thousand Oaks solar filter film here.

Comment: You can make one the way the guy in this video does. https://www.azuloxworkshops.com/educational/making-diy-solar-filter-eclipse/

Comment: I always buy the 12" squares. You can cut several filters from one sheet. I made two 80mm filters and two 60mm filters from one sheet and had plenty left over for future use. For roughly twice as much as the 5x5 inch square, you get 144 square inches of material instead of 25 square inches of material.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to make a solar filter: https://youtu.be/MwcqXpdOIBo. A cleaner way to use a step up ring and UV filter: https://youtu.be/2uFIOCyPBIU. It appears your lens has 77mm filter threads, so get a 77mm to 82mm step-up ring and an 82mm UV or clear filter. Cut a circle ofthe filter material just small enough to fit in the 82mm adapter ring and screw the 82mm clear filter in front of it to hold it in place.

Comment: @MichaelC so we are getting an Annular eclipse at 93.5% coverage. Is it safe to remove the solar filter during that moment, or is the 6.5% light still dangerous to mess up the camera? This might be a stupid question, but I'm looking to see if i can get on of those ring shots.

Comment: No, it's not safe. You only get ring shots with a total eclipse at the instants before and after the sun is 100% covered. the only time it is safe to remove filters is when the sun is 100% blocked.

Comment: @MichaelC thank you very much for all your support and guidance, I'm hoping to take some pictures with my new Thousands Oak Filter, hope everything goes out as planned. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect your camera from damage while shooting an eclipse, one needs a filter that attenuates infrared energy as well as visible light. Standard neutral density filters do not necessarily attenuate IR at all. It's not totally clear to me from the link for your filter that it is a proper solar filter or not. **Before using a filter on your camera to take pictures of the sun, you need to *positively confirm* that the filter is effective against UV and infrared wavelengths as well as visible light.**

It should go without saying that the filter needs to be placed in front of the front element of the lens. For larger telephoto lenses with "drop in" filter holders near the back of the lens, most of the glass and other parts of the lens will not be protected.

[image]

You will need the solar filter in place anytime the camera is pointed directly at the sun with any kind of telephoto lens attached. The sun will be bright enough that you will still be able to see it to focus using magnified Live View. I would recommend making some kind of shade to allow you to look at the camera's LCD screen and controls without exposing your eyes directly to the sun. I use foam board with a hole cut just large enough to fit the barrel of my lens through.

[image]

For a more about solar filters, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/101167/15871) to [What kind of filter do I need for safe sun photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101159/15871)
[How do I photograph the sunset without damaging my camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46390/15871)
[Can the sun damage the camera sensor? Under what conditions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4016/15871)

Comment: I understand ND filters won't remove UV and IR, how is this going to affect my sensor? Does UV and IR get magnified over a lens? My camera does not have a live viewfinder(as it is a mirrorless, so it is electronic), so I will not burn my eyes hopefully. I was thinking of using a piece of cardboard in front of my lens, as my sensor will be open all the time, whenever I take the picture, i will quickly take the cardboard away and put it back.The sun will appear around 40-70 degree in the sky, I will be looking down as i can turn my view screen up. This is all I have sadly, I need to make it work

Comment: **Found this on one of the reviews**. Bought for my camera for the solar eclipse in August. Was given a refund, even though I didn't request. Was told to NOT return it, but throw it away and don't use. I can only assume due to safety issues. It doesn't block UV, so it wouldn't be save to look through. I used Live View on my camera and put a UV filter in front of it. No issues with my camera or my vision. Just don't look through it with your eyes...ONLY LIVE VIEW.

Comment: **Another review.** under short periods of time live-view mode is perfectly safe to use. Longer durations of 5min or more should be avoided as the sensor is going to get warmed by the IR heat (particularly if amplified by a long lens which you will be using) and by minimizing the length of time it is going to avoid any harm to your equipment. all Modern cameras have a built in IR filter mounted to the sensor to assist with cutting IR light, and reducing heat for sharper images (more heat more noise). This built in filter also blocks a portion of IR light as well.

Comment: IR damage is dependent upon the strength of the lens. The longer the focal length and the wider the maximum aperture, the faster the lens and camera will be heated by the sun's energy. It took only a single minute to [do this to a Canon EOS 1Ds Mark III with a 600mm f/4 lens](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/News/News-Post.aspx?News=304)

Comment: The large shade not in the optical path of the lens is recommended to prevent you from looking directly into the sun with your unaided naked eyes while attempting to look at the screen on the back of your camera, since the sun will be directly past your camera when the camera is pointed at the sun and you are looking at the camera from behind. It will also allow you to see your screen more easily with the screen shaded from the sun if you have flipped your screen up so you can look down at it.

Comment: The IR filter in front of the sensor is not strong enough to prevent damage from pointing your camera directly at the sun with a telephoto lens. All of [these cameras](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2017/09/rental-camera-gear-destroyed-by-the-solar-eclipse-of-2017/) also had IR filters in front of the sensor. A filter at the sensor does *nothing* to protect the lens or even your camera's shutter mechanism (many mirrorless cameras do - the shutter closes just before exposure, operates to take the image, then opens back up - to deal with rolling shutter effect due to electronic shutter).