# Could I have destroyed my Lumix GX80 by taking sun photos?

Tags: optics, mirrorless, panasonic-lumix, sun

So I shooted architecture photos during a cloudy day but the lighting was very bright and you could see sun directly in some moments. I was shooting and I noticed that I needed to adjust aperture (close it) so I can shoot normal photos. I didn't notice this before so I am afraid that I damaged aperture because of exposing my camera to sun and bright light. Is this damage likely or possible or am I just caring too much about this?

I usually shoot in afternoon and always take care of my lenses but this was a tourist trip to Budapest and my camera was around my neck the whole day from morning to afternoon without the cap on lenses. My camera is a Panasonic Lumix GX80 and the lenses I was using were kit (12-35mm and 35-100mm).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the sun damage the camera sensor? Under what conditions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/can-the-sun-damage-the-camera-sensor-under-what-conditions)

Comment: Also related: [Can Low speed shutter damage Camera in Bright light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96626/15871) and [Can the sun damage a point and shoot camera's sensor even when it is off?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41746/15871) and [Can the sun damage the sensor on a mirrorless camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89934/15871)

Answer (score 2):

Not too likely. What makes you think your camera is damaged?

A sensor burned out should be quite easy to notice on recent pictures (assuming it works at all), and other damage (bent diaphragm) should prevent correctly exposed pictures.

To damage your camera you would need a rather long lens, and a significant time facing the sun (for instance when using a tripod). See [here](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2017/09/rental-camera-gear-destroyed-by-the-solar-eclipse-of-2017/) for some examples.

Comment: Most lenses are always open at max aperture, except during the short time the picture is taken. There are plenty of pictures with the sun in the frame on the net, they didn't kill the camera. The longer lenses capture more light/energy, a 400mm f/.56 is twice the diameter of a 50mm f/1.4 (so 4 tiles the energy) and when the sun is in the frame a lot more is direct sun rays...

Comment: Has the exposure compensation been altered? This somehow happened to me with my Gx80 (fat finger issue) . Took me a while to figure out what I'd done!